# Sitemap.php para Sitemap.xml

Tags: php, xml, htaccess

Alguém pode me ajudar? fiz um arquivo "sitemap.php" tudo ok, só que quero que ele possa ser acessado em "sitemap.xml" também.

Meu .htaccess;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|favicon.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>  
# CONFIGURAR UTILIZAÇÃO DO HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://meusite.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://meusite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: O .htaccess é um arquivo especial para o Apache. Quando um usuário está navegando por alguma página do seu site, para todo diretório que ele tentar acessar, o Apache procura primeiro pelo tal do arquivo .htaccess e se encontrar, verifica se existe alguma restrição ou configuração especial. nesse site https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ gera o sitemap de forma automatica.

Comment: Olá Henrique já conseguir resolver como faço para o tópico ser fechado?

Answer (score 0):

Gente conseguir resolver, esqueci de adicionar .php e .xml no .htaccess;

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|favicon.ico|sitemap\.xml|sitemap\.php)
```